# Convert variables between camel case and underscore style

Tags: sublime-text-2

I would like to convert variables from or to `UpperCamelCase`, `lowerCamelCase`, `underscore_style`, or even "`separate by spaces`". This would be useful for coding and making documentation.

I use Sublime Text 2. Can this be done in this editor?

Comment: Python can do that with its' str methods. Other than that, remember about product recommendations.

Comment: It wouldn't be that hard to do with substitution regexes (perl ?)

Comment: Your Notepad++ solution is here, so I removed the tag from this question: [Use Notepad++ to change under_score_case to CamelCase?](http://superuser.com/questions/312073/use-notepad-to-change-under-score-case-to-camelcase)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The [Case Conversion plugin](https://github.com/jdc0589/CaseConversion) can do this for Sublime Text.

You can install it with [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Case%20Conversion). If you haven't done so, install Package Control first, then press <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-Shift-P</kbd>, go to *Package Control, Install Package*, and install *Case Conversion*.

It adds new entries to your *Convert Case* menu.

[image]

Comment: This plugin is so useful

Comment: Feel stupid for not looking into this sooner, saves soooo much time

Comment: can this be used with sublime 3? I can't find the package when I search for Case Conversion as per the instructions

Comment: Yes it works on ST3

Comment: Still works; just tested on Sublime Text 4 build 4126.