# SublimeText 3 and ConvertCase package beginner installation problems

Tags: installation, plugins, sublime-text-3

I've freshly installed Sublime Text build 3114 and started to explore it's functionality. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/635690/convert-variables-between-camel-case-and-underscore-style) I've found that it is possible to install [Case Conversion plugin](https://github.com/jdc0589/CaseConversion). Mentioned page shows two possibilities of installation:

1. using [Package Control plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/)
2. manual installation

1st approach did not worked for me (see logs bellow) so I've used 2nd approach. My sublime text is located in `C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3` directory. [Case Conversion plugin](https://github.com/jdc0589/CaseConversion) site claims that this plugin should be installed where ever the `Preferences -> Browse Packages` option in Sublime takes you. Mine points to `C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` so I've cloned repo in `C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages\User\CaseConversion-master`.

I'm trying to change case in following file (example taken from [here](http://thecrumb.com/2011/10/27/sublime-text-package-of-the-day-case-conversion/))

```
this_is_something
this_is_something
this_is_something
```

I've clicked on first occurrence of `this_is_something` and press `ctrl+d` then I've navigated to `Edit -> Convert Case` but as you can see on following picture there are non active cases:

[image: this picture]

Here is log from console immediately after Sublime Text start:

```
DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3114 windows x32 channel: stable
executable: /C/Users/wakatana/Downloads/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /c/Users/wakatana/Downloads/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/wakatana/Downloads/Sublime Text 3/Data/Packages
state path: /C/Users/wakatana/Downloads/Sublime Text 3/Data/Local
zip path: /C/Users/wakatana/Downloads/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/wakatana/Downloads/Sublime Text 3/Data/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 1.86239
startup time: 7.79439
first paint time: 7.79439
first paint time: 7.79539
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
plugins loaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 162, in on_api_ready
    m.plugin_loaded()
  File "2_bootstrap in C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 103, in plugin_loaded
  File "package_control.loader in C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 193, in add
  File "./python3.3/zipfile.py", line 921, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\wakatana\\Downloads\\Sublime Text 3\\Installed Packages\\0_package_control_loader.sublime-package'
Package Control: Not running package cleanup since bootstrapping is not yet complete
```

Here is log after I type `pci` (`Package Control: Install Package`) in to `Command palette... (ctrl+shift+p)`

```
Package Control: Fetching list of available packages
  Platform: windows-x32
  Sublime Text Version: 3114
  Package Control Version: 3.1.2
Package Control: Download Debug
  URL: https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json
  Timeout: 120
  Resolved IP: 50.116.33.29
Package Control: WinINet Debug Proxy
  proxy: XXX:3128
  proxy bypass: XXX:3128 <local>
  proxy username: 
  proxy password: 
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug General
  Server SSL Certificate:
    subject: US, Massachusetts, Private Organization, 471714639, US, Massachusetts, Newbury, Codex Non Sufficit LC, codexns.io
    issuer: US, GeoTrust Inc., GeoTrust EV SSL CA - G4
    common name: codexns.io
    issue date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 02:00:00 GMT
    expire date: Mon, 28 Nov 2016 00:59:59 GMT
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug Write
  GET /channel_v3.json HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: Package Control v3.1.2
  Host: packagecontrol.io
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Accept-Encoding: bzip2,gzip,deflate
  If-None-Match: "5745ad91-3f11b"
  If-Modified-Since: Wed, 25 May 2016 13:50:09 GMT
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug Read
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 14:55:26 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 259521
  Last-Modified: Wed, 25 May 2016 14:50:09 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "5745bba1-3f5c1"
  Content-Encoding: bzip2
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
Package Control: Caching https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json in C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages\User\Package Control.cache\01524fae79697630d0454ba3fabd9414
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug General
  Closing connection to packagecontrol.io on port 443 after 1 request
```

And here is log after I choose `Case Conversion` from `Package Control: Install Package`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package_control.package_installer in C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 159, in on_done
  File "package_control.package_disabler in C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 74, in disable_packages
ImportError: No module named 'package_control'
```

Previously I've installed `Package Control.sublime-package` in `C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Packages` opposite to `C:\Users\wakatana\Downloads\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` for [Case Conversion plugin](https://github.com/jdc0589/CaseConversion).

I've also changed proxy to following (using [this](http://9to5it.com/sublime-text-installation-configuration/) tutorial):

```
{
    "debug" : true,
    "timeout" : 120,
    "http_proxy": "http://XXX:8080/",
    "https_proxy": "http://XXX:8080/",
}
```

What is difference between `Data\Packages` and `Packages` directory under Sublime Text?

Why I'm not able to install [Case Conversion plugin](https://github.com/jdc0589/CaseConversion) using [Package Control plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/)?

Why [Case Conversion plugin](https://github.com/jdc0589/CaseConversion) isn't working?

Why I get errors in console?

PS: I've cross posted this to [official ST forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/st3-and-convertcase-package-beginner-installation-problems/20448).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.sublime-package` file is a zipped package and should be installed in `Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages`. Only extracted packages go into `Sublime Text 3\Packages\` (or its `User` sub-folder).

The error message sounds to me like Package Control wasn't installed properly. If you want to install it manually, follow these steps from the Package Control [installation guide](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

1. Click the `Preferences > Browse Packages…` menu
2. Browse up a folder and then into the `Installed Packages/` folder
3. Download `Package Control.sublime-package` and copy it into the `Installed Packages/` directory
4. Restart Sublime Text

Comment: Thanks. Seems that I screwed up installation of `PackageControl` plugin. Previously I've put `Package Control.sublime-package` inside `.\Packages` directory but proper location for is under `.\Data\Installed Packages` directory.